# How to convert rows into columns (as value but not header) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

In the following dataset, I need to convert each row for the “description” under “name" column (for example, inventory1, inventory2 and inventory3)  into two separate columns (namely description1 and description2, respectively). If I used either pviot_table or groupby, the value of the description will become header instead of a value under a column. What would be the way to generate the desired output? Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = { 'item':['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5','item6'],
  'name':['inventory1','inventory1','inventory2','inventory2','inventory3','inventory3'],
  'code':[1,1,2,2,3,3],
  'description':['sales number decrease compared to last month', 'Sales number 
decreased','sales number increased','Sales number increased, need to keep kpi','no sales this 
month','item out of stock']}

df1=pd.DataFrame(df1)
```

desired output as below:
[image]

Comment: Your example is not clear. You talk about "the same inventory item", but how to choose the value for the "item" column? For example, in the first row: why "item1" and not "item2"? Also, will you always have exactly two rows for the same inventory?

Comment: I modified the question slightly. Need to convert the description under each “name” column into two columns. Also, I will not always have 2 rows for each inventory (under “name” column), sometimes I have 3 or 4 but I didn’t want to make the question too confusing. If there’s a way to do this(automatically convert different numbers of rows into corresponding numbers of columns) , it’d be super helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use `pd.concat`:

```
new_df = pd.concat([
        (
            df.drop_duplicates('name')
            .drop('description', axis=1)
            .reset_index(drop=True)
        ),
        (
            pd.DataFrame([pd.Series(l) for l in df.groupby('name')['description'].agg(list).tolist()])
            .add_prefix('description')
        ),
    ],
    axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
    item        name  code                                  description0                              description1
0  item1  inventory1     1  sales number decrease compared to last month                    Sales number decreased
1  item3  inventory2     2                        sales number increased  Sales number increased, need to keep kpi
2  item5  inventory3     3                           no sales this month                         item out of stock
```

<sub>One-liner version of the above, in case you want it:</sub>

```
pd.concat([df.drop_duplicates('name').drop('description', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True), pd.DataFrame([pd.Series(l) for l in df.groupby('name')['description'].agg(list).tolist()]).add_prefix('description')], axis=1)
```